# Is there a MySQLAdmin or SQL Server Management Studio equivalent for SQLite databases on Windows?

Tags: sql, windows, sqlite

I need some software to explore and modify some SQLite databases.  Does anything similar to SQL Server Management Studio or MySQLAdmin exist for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[As a Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817) (aimed mainly at gears, but should work)

[As a (sucky) web based app](http://www.sqlitemanager.org)

And [a big list of management tools](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools)

Comment: If you are after a free windows one, I recommend [SQLite Studio](http://sqlitestudio.one.pl/) from Vinko's list above, I have tried a few of them out.

Comment: I've found [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index) to be pretty good. Feels a lot snappier than SQLite Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I also discovered some SQLite software for Visual Studio at http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/ which allows you to use the Visual Studio Server Explorer to create connections to SQLite databases.

Answer (score 0):

SQLiteManager (the Firefox Plugin mentioned by Vinko) also works well as a standalone app, with XULRunner.